# VideoJS Resolution Switcher not restarting automatically after switching bit-rates in Flash mode

Tags: javascript, flash, video.js

We're trying to offer the ability to switch between different video bitrates using the resolution switcher plugin (https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher) for a video.js player.

Here is a demo page with basic setup to run videojs player in flash mode: [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/xinutat) (click on 'edit in jsbin on your top right to see the actual code)

The plugin works correct in HTML5 (DASH and HLS) streaming but fails in Flash mode. The player will start playing with default bitrate value ('1080p' in this case) without any issues. The problem occurs when you actually switch the bitrate. If you select to change to a different bit-rate the player will stop playing. No browser console errors, player will not crash, just freezing. Seems like the player even doesn't sent the actual http request to get the new video source. Sometimes plugin even can actually switch the source, but it's happened just few times and randomly. In other words the behavior is way unstable and not acceptable.

Plugin provides `resolutionchange` event which should be fired when resolution is changed, but it's not. Only UI changes are visible.

I'm really appreciate on any help or ideas on how this behavior can be fixed!

Also including it here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .video-js { background-color: black; }
    video { width: 100%; height: 100% }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.16.0/video.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.1.0/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dashjs/2.4.0/dash.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-dash/2.7.1/videojs-dash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-resolution-switcher/0.4.2/videojs-resolution-switcher.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="450" height="250"></video>

  <script>
    videojs('player', {
      preload: 'auto',
      autoplay: true,
      techOrder: ["flash"],
      controls: true,
      plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
          default: 1080,
          dynamicLabel: true
        }
      }
    }, function(){
      handleReady(this);
    });

    var sources=[
      {src:"rtmp://stagingmedia.livecoding.tv/livecodingtv/1080p_irwanbd?t=FDD4A16B14C34359A8677A339962B60D",label:"HQ",type:"rtmp/mp4",res:1080},
      {src:"rtmp://stagingmedia.livecoding.tv/livecodingtv/720p_irwanbd?t=FDD4A16B14C34359A8677A339962B60D",label:"Medium",type:"rtmp/mp4",res:720},
      {src:"rtmp://stagingmedia.livecoding.tv/livecodingtv/480p_irwanbd?t=FDD4A16B14C34359A8677A339962B60D",label:"Low",type:"rtmp/mp4",res:480}
    ];

    function handleReady(player) {
      window.player = player;
      player.updateSrc(sources);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = videojs('video', {
    controls: true,
    muted: true,
    width: 800,
    plugins: {
        videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
            ui: true,
            default: '< default_res >', // Default resolution [{Number},   'low', 'high'],
            dynamicLabel: false
        }
   }
}, 
function() {
    player.updateSrc([ < sourcetags > ]);
    player.on('resolutionchange', function(){
        player.play();
        console.info('Source changed to %s', player.src());
    })
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question